# Differentiate between two join tables AR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two join tables attached to a Customer model. The join tables hold the foreign keys. One of the join tables refers to a shipping_address, and the other a billing_address. How to I filter for one or the other?

Answer (score 1):

A simple join query looks like this:

```
Customer.joins(:address_table1).where(address_table1: {shipping_address: address})
```

see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joins for more